# How to print the list of map values using scala

Tags: scala

I have written the following code

```
val list = List(
  Map("empid" -> "12", "empName" -> "Rohan", "depId" -> "201"),
  Map("empid" -> "13", "empName" -> "swathi", "depId" -> "202")
).flatten.toMap

val mapRDD= sc.parallelize(Seq(list))

val columns=mapRDD.take(1).flatMap(a=>a.keys)

val columnval=mapRDD.take(2).flatMap(a=>a.keys)

val resultantDF=mapRDD.map{value=>

      val list=value.values.toList

      (list(0),list(1),list(2))

      }.toDF(columns:_*)



resultantDF.show()
```

i am expecting the below output,

+-----+-------+-----+

|empid|empName|depId|

+-----+-------+-----+

|   12| Rohan|  201|

|   13|SWATHI|202 |

but i am getting only,

+-----+-------+-----+

|empid|empName|depId|

+-----+-------+-----+
|   13|SWATHI|202

Please let me know where i am doing the mistake.

Comment: Use `List((Map("empid" -> "12", "empName" -> "Rohan", "depId" -> "201")), (Map("empid" -> "13", "empName" -> "swathi", "depId" -> "202"))).flatten.map(x => (x._1, x._2))` will be resolved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your first line only,

```
scala> val list = List(
 |   Map("empid" -> "12", "empName" -> "Rohan", "depId" -> "201"),
 |   Map("empid" -> "13", "empName" -> "swathi", "depId" -> "202")
 | ).flatten.toMap
// list: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(empid -> 13, empName -> swathi, depId -> 202)
```

Your `list` actually ends up becoming a `Map`. And a `Map` can have only 1 value for each key.

Let's do the first line step by step,

So, first you created a `list of maps`,

```
scala> val listOfMaps = List(
 |   Map("empid" -> "12", "empName" -> "Rohan", "depId" -> "201"),
 |   Map("empid" -> "13", "empName" -> "swathi", "depId" -> "202")
 | )
// list: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = List(Map(empid -> 12, empName -> Rohan, depId -> 201), Map(empid -> 13, empName -> swathi, depId -> 202))
```

Then, you `flattened` the `maps` inside the `listOfMaps` which will result in a list of `key-value` pairs.

```
scala> val flattenedListOfMaps = listOfMaps.flatten
// flattenedListOfMaps: List[(String, String)] = List((empid,12), (empName,Rohan), (depId,201), (empid,13), (empName,swathi), (depId,202))
```

Now, you are converting it to a `Map` using `toMap`, which will keep on overriding the values of keys and result in a `Map` with unique keys,

```
scala> scala> val yourMap = flattenedListOfMaps.toMap
// yourMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(empid -> 13, empName -> swathi, depId -> 202)
```

Comment: so what is the best approach to solve this. Kindly help

Comment: If you want it to be a list of maps, then don't `flatten.toMap`.

Comment: Sorry its my bad miss interpretation..Thanks its working now.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the previous answer and comment, at the moment your list variable is actually a map (which is confusing at least).
What you probably want initially as input is a list.
Hence what you need is:

1.
get rid of `.flatten.toMap`:

```
val list = List(
  Map("empid" -> "12", "empName" -> "Rohan", "depId" -> "201"),
  Map("empid" -> "13", "empName" -> "swathi", "depId" -> "202")
)
```

2.
Also when calling `sc.parallelize` you don't need to create a separate Seq from original input (in fact, otherwise you would have a compile error).
So you also need to change it like this:

```
val mapRDD = sc.parallelize(list)
```

After making only those two changes you will receive expected result, i.e. 2 records shown in console output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working.. in my code i am using list(0),list(1),list(3) to show the list of values here i got only 3 headers so i am displaying like this. How to handle this to support dynamic values like list may contain more than 3 headers.

Comment: That's another question which should be addressed separately. I can take a look. Meanwhile if my solution works and you like it could you please accept or upvote it.

Comment: Could you please help me on that.